# Google App Engine Guestbook application gives error

Tags: google-app-engine

I upload the Google App Engine application which is at the url developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache#Memcache

When I run the application on Google App Engine Launcher, it runs but the website shows: 
(First error is there us no Python "PIL" module but I am not using image. Could you please suggest what is causing the error?

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=13080 --admin_port=8005
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:22,217 devappserver2.py:660] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-01-17 20:43:22,222 api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:22,226 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: localhost:55385
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:22,230 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: localhost:13080
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:22,238 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: localhost:8005
ERROR    2014-01-17 20:43:24,601 wsgi.py:262] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 301, in _LoadHandler
    raise err
ImportError: <module 'guestbookw2' from '/Users/guestbookw2/guestbookw2.pyc'> has no attribute application
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:24,607 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2014-01-17 20:43:24,727 wsgi.py:262] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 301, in _LoadHandler
    raise err
ImportError: <module 'guestbookw12' from '/Users/guestbookw2/guestbookw2.pyc'> has no attribute application
INFO     2014-01-17 20:43:24,732 module.py:617] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: The answer below addresses at least one of the errors listed in the question above ("GET /favicon.ico ..."), so down-voting it isn't very polite to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the following files in the path that you are uploading your application from:

1. **index.yaml** (auto-generated; you don't need to add or change anything in here at this point).
2. **favicon.ico** (in the correct format; should be 16x16 or 32x32 pixels if I remember correctly).
3. **main.py** (mapping all the paths in your web-site; example given below):

   ```
   from webapp2 import WSGIApplication
   from Server import MainRequestHandler
   from Server import SomeRequestHandler
   from Server import OtherRequestHandler

   app = WSGIApplication([
       ('/'              ,MainRequestHandler),
       ('/abc'           ,SomeRequestHandler),
       ('/def'           ,SomeRequestHandler),
       ('/xyz'           ,OtherRequestHandler),
   ])
   ```
4. **app.yaml** (with the following contents; using `<...>` where you need to set a value):

   ```
   application: <the app-id you chose when use signed in for GAE>
   version: 1
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: yes

   handlers:
   - url: /favicon\.ico
     static_files: favicon.ico
     upload: favicon\.ico

   - url: .*
     script: main.app

   libraries:
   - name: webapp2
     version: "2.5.1" // you might need to change this as well
   ```

**Note**:

if you wish to avoid handling 'favicon.ico' request, then you must remove the reference in file 'app.yaml'.

**Supplemental**:

You will need to implement all the request handlers imported in 'main.py'.

In the example above, 'main.py' expects to find them in a Python module named 'Server'.

Each request handler must inherit `class RequestHandler`, imported from `webapp2`.

**Supplemental #2**:

In order to solve the 'PIL' issue (had a similar problem if memory serves correctly), simply install it.

From a Windows command line, enter: pip install pil.

Comment: I updated the main.py file. Instead of "app = ", I wrote "application = "... and it now works.

Comment: First of all, if in file app.yaml you have 'script: main.app' (as in my answer above), then the name of this variable should be `app`. So you probably have 'script: main.application' in your app.yaml file. Second, why did you down-vote this answer???

Comment: Yes in my app.yaml file it is main.application . Thanks. I did not down-vote. I do not even see any vote sign with my login.